# How to add Bing UET tag using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, tracking, bing

I wanted to know how to add Bing UET tag using AngularJS + ui-router. I've already added the Bing UET tag to the confirmation page but is not tracking any conversions.

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by placing the UET Tag in the '$stateChangeSuccess' event of the UI Router. This makes your code looks as follows:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    // Your UET Tag here
}
```

Hope this helps!